# Magento 2: How to add Grand Total in base currency to the PDF invoice?

Tags: magento2, currency, invoice-pdf

I need to display the grand total base currency value on invoices that have been generated using other currencies than base. And want to display all the values on the PDF invoice could be displayed in both currencies. Please see attached image for better understanding.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Any solution please ? i need to print invoice with the 2 currencies

Comment: yes. i created event for it. event name is sales_order_place_after. and save value of currency that we need to display. and then do calculate with the base currency

Comment: @Ronak Can you tell me how you did it ? Can you share that code in reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All the data you need is already in the order object and Magento allows you to easily add to the various order totals in your own module using a `pdf.xml` config files.

Create a new module in the usual way. In that module add an `etx/pdf.xml` config file with the contents:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf_file.xsd">
    <totals>
        <total name="base_grand_total">
            <title translate="true">Base Grand Total</title>
            <source_field>base_grand_total</source_field>
            <font_size>8</font_size>
            <display_zero>true</display_zero>
            <sort_order>800</sort_order>
            <model><My Namespace>\<My Module>\Model\Order\Pdf\BaseGrandTotal</model>
        </total>
    </totals>
</config>
```

The title, is what will show up on the PDF invoice. The source_field, is the database column name you want to display, which, as you want to display the base currency grand total, should be 'base_grand_total'.

The sort order sets the relative position of your total in the last section of the invoice. As of M2.3.5, the grand total has a sort order of 700, so setting this to 800 places it at the end of the invoice. If you search the code base for `pdf.xml`, you'll find all the other config files which get merged together. Take a look at the `total` nodes within the `totals` node and that will let you see which totals will be included and their relative position by sort order.

If you ran the above without including the `model` node, you'd get the figure you were after, but with a currency symbol that matched the order currency. This is because the `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal` class uses the orders `formatPriceTxt` method, which in turn uses the order currency for the formatting, not the base currency. To handle this, you need the `model` node above to point your own subclass of `DefaultTotal`, where you can modify the behaviour to use the the base currency for the formatting.

Add the class, referenced above in your `pdf.xml` to your module. In the file `<My Namespace>/<My Module>/Model/Order/Pdf/BaseGrandTotal.php` add the content:

```
namespace <My Namespace>\<My Module>\Model\Order\Pdf;

class BaseGrandTotal extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal
{
    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        $fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;

        $amount = $this->getOrder()->getBaseCurrency()->formatTxt($this->getAmount());

        $totals = [
            [
                'amount' => $this->getAmountPrefix() . $amount,
                'label' => __($this->getTitle()) . ':',
                'font_size' => $fontSize,
            ],
        ];

        return $totals;
    }
}
```

This formats the `amount` using the base currency of the order, not the order currency.

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine. and For subtotal and shipping how to i can display in base currency ?